# Decoding JSON with unknown structure

Tags: php, javascript, json

I'm looking to get the structure of a JSON object without the predefined knowledge of what it may contain. To elaborate, I could be given

```
[{"x":0,"y":0.4991088274400681,"z":7.489443555361306}, {"x":0,"y":0.7991088274400681,"z":7.489343555361306},{"x":0,"y":0.5991088274400681,"z":7.482445555361306}]
```

or even something crazy like:

```
'AL': {name:'Alabama', landarea:131426, waterarea:4338, population:[3525342,4243844]},
'AK': {name:'Alaska', landarea:1418400, waterarea:234324, population:[43230943,43230943]}
```

In other words, I have no idea what kind of JSON I'm going to get, but I'd like to know that there's x, y and z in the first one with an associated value, or AL, AK and name, landarea, waterarea, and an array of populations in the second.

This is sort of like getting the column headers in excel. **I know that there will a repetitive structure, though.**

Is the only way to parse this by using JSON_decode and then doing typeOf examinations to see if what I have is an Object/Array/String? It seems rather clunky.

Comment: I would ask for new api, it should not be returning you two different sets of data to one request

Comment: It's not that the api is returning different sets of data, it's just that I'm parsing user-fed JSON that can be in different formats. A little dangerous, I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A browser's native JSON decoding function can handle any well-formed JSON. What you want is a function that can *understand* the decoded JSON. That is not possible, at least not when you have absolutely no prior knowledge of, or a way of handling, the data. However, if all you want to know is the data type for each component, then `typeof` will work fine.

Comment: agreed - json_decode already tells you that property x has an array of y elements, for example.. it's implicit. Seems the OP is trying to gather extra semantic meaning and there is no way of doing this without *some* prior knowledge.

Comment: Thank you. At least I can proceed without worrying too much that I'm trying to reinvent the wheel.